# argparse with multiple flags and arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want my code to be able to call different functions according to the flag and then use the argument passed after the flag as the input to the function.

Example of the expected output:

```
$ python3 test.py -a 2
4

$ python3 test.py -a human123
<Error message>

$ python3 test.py -h human123
Hello, human123
```

Here's my sample code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def add(self, a):
        return a+a

    def hello(self, name):
        return f"Hello, {name}"

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-a', '--add', dest='command', action='store_consts', const='add', nargs=1, help='add a to itself')
parser.add_argument('-h', '--hello', dest='command', action='store_consts', const='hello', nargs=1, help='hello!')

args = parser.parse_args()
t = Test()

if args.command=='add':
    print(t.add(args.add))
elif args.command=='sub':
    print(t.hello(args.hello))
```

This sample code currently is doing what I want to achieve. I tried many things to fix the issue from removing the 'consts', changing the action to 'store', changing the value of nargs to '?', etc., however, it keeps giving me different kinds of errors like TypeError, etc.

Comment: With 'store_const' you can't use `nargs`.  Aren't the docs clear on that?

Comment: Step back; omit the `dest`, `action` and `nargs` and `const`.  Then print `args` for the different inputs.  Bet there's enough info to write your `if` lines.

Comment: I definitely suggest re-reading (or reading) the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Thank you for the input. I definitely need to spend more time reading the documentation and understanding of every single piece of information properly. All I missed turns out is just another argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifying your arguments:

```
import argparse

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def add(self, a):
        return a+a

    def hello(self, name):
        return f"Hello, {name}"

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-a', '--add', help='add a to itself')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--hello', help='hello!')         # -h is already taken

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
t = Test()

if args.add:                # or 'args.add is not None:'
    print(t.add(args.add))
elif args.hello:
    print(t.hello(args.hello))
```

test runs:

```
1936:~/mypy$ python3 stack62702524.py -a testing
Namespace(add='testing', hello=None)
testingtesting
1937:~/mypy$ python3 stack62702524.py -b other
Namespace(add=None, hello='other')
Hello, other
1937:~/mypy$ python3 stack62702524.py 
Namespace(add=None, hello=None)
```

===

Your errors, which you did not show :{   When you get errors, don't just throw up your hands and randomly try alternatives.  Read the docs and try to understand the error.

```
parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_consts', const='hello')
ValueError: unknown action "store_consts"

parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_const', const='hello', nargs=1)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nargs'
```

'store_consts' is an name error;  with 'store_const' `nargs` is fixed at 0; you can't change that.

If I add 3 arguments - two store_const and one positional:

```
parser.add_argument('-c', dest='command', action='store_const', const='add')
parser.add_argument('-d', dest='command', action='store_const', const='hello')
parser.add_argument('foo')
```

Note the two new `command` and `foo` attributes, which you could use in your function call:

```
1945:~/mypy$ python3 stack62702524.py -c bar
Namespace(add=None, command='add', foo='bar', hello=None)
1945:~/mypy$ python3 stack62702524.py -d bar
Namespace(add=None, command='hello', foo='bar', hello=None)
```

Comment: Thank you this makes more sense. I definitely need to spend more time reading the documentation and understanding of every single piece of information properly. All I missed turns out is just another argument.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I use the `dest` parameter of `add_argument` to specify the variable name.

For example:

```
parser.add_argument("-a", "--add", dest="add", required=False, type=str help="some help")
```

Could be accessed by:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.add == "something")
```

I believe that you need one unique `dest` per argument.

Also, `-h` is reserved for help. You may wish to change this to `-e` or something.

> ```
> parser.add_argument('-h', '--hello', ...)
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the issue. I need to command to tell my code which flag it is. By removing the command, my code can't tell which function to call. Any advice?

Comment: @ThomasWest I don't think you understand, your code makes zero sense. Look at your code. If `dest` (aka "destination" aka the "name" of the argument in `args`) is `command` then `args.add` does not exist. Only `args.command` does. What do you expect `args.add` to be?

Comment: Thank you for the input. I definitely need to spend more time reading the documentation and understanding of every single piece of information properly. All I missed turns out is just another argument.